# Estimating the mean of a normal distribution using hard thresholding

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value, numerical-optimization

Say I have $n$ i.i.d. samples $x_1,\cdots, x_n$ from a normal distribution $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$. I want to estimate the mean $\mu$ using the hard thresholding estimator $\mu^* = \bar{x}1_{|\bar{x}| \ge \alpha}$, i.e. $\mu^* = \bar{x}$ if $\bar{x}$ is $\ge \alpha$ or $\le -\alpha$ and $\mu^* = 0$ otherwise. I am trying to find the optimal $\alpha$ such that $E(x - \mu^*)^2$ is minimized.

So
$$
\begin{aligned}
E(x - \mu^*)^2 &= E(x - \mu + \mu - \mu^*)^2 \\
&= E[(x-\mu)^2] + E[(\mu - \mu^*)^2] \\
&= \sigma^2+ \mu^2 + \mu^2 + \sigma^2/n - \int_{-\alpha}^\alpha x^2p(x)dx - 2\mu^2 + 2\mu\int_{-\alpha}^\alpha xp(x)dx \\
& = \sigma^2+\sigma^2/n - \int_{-\alpha}^\alpha x^2p(x)dx + 2\mu\int_{-\alpha}^\alpha xp(x)dx \\
&=\sigma^2+\sigma^2/n + \int_{-\alpha}^\alpha (2\mu x- x^2)p(x) dx
\end{aligned}
$$
where $p(x)$ is the normal density with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2/n$ (the density of $\bar{x}$).
If I differentiate this with respect to $\alpha$ and set that to $0$, I get
$$
\begin{aligned}
(2\mu\alpha-\alpha^2)p(\alpha) + [2\mu(-\alpha)-\alpha^2]p(\alpha) = -\alpha^4p(\alpha) = 0
\end{aligned}
$$
But since normal density is an exponential function, which is non-zero, does this imply that only $\alpha = 0$ satisfies the above equation? This does not seem right to me. Can someone point out what I did wrong? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Thanks to the comment by @Andreas Lenz, I realized that I mistakenly use $p(α)=p(−α)$ in the last step, so my last step should really be $(2\mu \alpha − \alpha^2)p(\alpha)-[2\mu\alpha+\alpha^2]p(-\alpha) = 0$. $\alpha = 0$ and $\alpha = \infty$ are certainly two solutions to the equation, but I am just wondering whether there exists a closed form of the minimizer other than these two extreme values, since setting $\alpha = 0$ or $\alpha = \infty$ defeats the purpose of my estimator. Any suggestions or hints would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The MSE of the sample mean is $\sigma^2/n$, but the MSE of just guessing $\mu = 0$ would be a function of $\mu$, right? So if the $\mu$ is very close to $0$, wouldn't guess $\mu = 0$ yield a smaller MSE?

Comment: You're right. For some reason I was assuming a Bayesian setting here. I have two other questions, though. Why are you minimizing $E(x-\mu^*)^2$ as opposed to $E(\mu-\mu^*)^2$? And could you shortly elaborate on how you find $E(\mu^*)$ and  $E(\mu^*)^2$?

Comment: 1. I think both would work, since $E(x-\mu^*)^2 = E(x-\mu)^2 + E(\mu - \mu^*)^2$. i.e. they only differ by a constant term. 2. I just used the property that $E(\mu^*) = E(\bar{x}) - \int_{-\alpha}^{\alpha} xp(x)dx$, where $p(x)$ is the density of sampling distribution of $\bar{x}$, which is also normal.

Comment: Ah, but then could it be that you mistakenly use $p(\alpha)=p(-\alpha)$ in the last step?

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is within the differentiation. If you differentiate the MSE with respect to $\alpha$, you obtain
$$ (2\mu\alpha-\alpha^2)p(\alpha) + (2\mu(-\alpha)-(-\alpha)^2)p(-\alpha) = (2\mu\alpha-\alpha^2)p(\alpha) - (2\mu\alpha+\alpha^2)p(-\alpha). $$
Notice that you cannot use $p(\alpha)=p(-\alpha)$ here, since $\mu$ is not necessarily $0$.

You further need to take care when searching for the minimizer $\alpha^*$ as it might also be equal to $0$ or $\infty$. Thus the derivative does not necessarily vanish at the minimizing point.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake! Are you suggesting that the minimizer is either $0$ or $\infty$ and does not have a closed form?

Comment: Glad to help. Numerically it seems that either $0$ or $\infty$ minimize the MSE. As you see from this plot (https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5CmB.png), which plots $\int_{-\alpha}^\alpha (2\mu x- x^2)p(x) dx$ for $\sigma=1$ and several values of $\mu$ over $\alpha$. It appears that in that case for $\mu<1$, $\alpha=\infty$ minimizes the MSE and for $\mu>1$, $\alpha=0$ minimizes the MSE. I'll see if we can do something analytically and keep you updated if I find something, provided that you are interested.

Comment: That's very interesting! I think this graph is suggesting that hard-thresholding is somewhat pointless if $\sigma =1$. I will try different values of $\sigma$ and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @InsultedByMathematics Yeah, I agree. It further appears that in general, when  $\mu^2<\sigma^2/n$, you want to choose $\alpha=\infty$ and when $\mu^2 \geq\sigma^2/n$, you want to choose $\alpha=0$. However, this was just observed through numerical plots and I have not quite managed to prove this analytically.